Waydroid ABI error when installing APK
I bought a new laptop, installed Ubuntu 24.04, downloaded from apkmirror.com the APK's I want to use (including APKMirror Installer) to play games, copied these APK's to my home directory's .local/share/waydroid/data/media/0/Download (I could then see the APK's in Waydroid), installed APKMirror in Waydroid with no problem but when I try to install any game APK I get the following error:
"The system failed to install the package because its packaged native code did not match any of the ABIs supported by the system"
My Waydroid Parameters "About phone" shows "WayDroid x86_64 Device". Help!

Do you know for sure the apps you tried to install are known to work with Ubuntu 24.04? You may want to visit the web site and find out.

APKs are for Android OS. Ubuntu is Linux. They don't run natively in Ubuntu. Edit your question and add exactly each step of what you installed.

I found the cause of my problem this morning. To my horror, I discoved that most applications for cell phone or tablet support either the ARM or x86 architecture, but not both. Very few, maybe 10% from what I've seen, support both: they are qualified as Universal. Applications being dependant on the underlying hardware is beyond me. Sorry to have bothered you guys.
